# How can I execute a simple Applescript from a C++ program?

Tags: c++, macos, applescript, appleevents

I would like to execute the Applescript command `tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file */path/to/somefilename*` from a C++ program. It looks like I might want to use `OSACompileExecute`, but I haven't been able to find an example of how to use it. I keep finding examples of how to use the `OSACompile` Terminal command. Can someone provide an example or a link to an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, the trick was to not bother trying to compile and execute the Applescript but to simply use the `osascript` system command:

```
    sprintf(cmd, "osascript -e 'tell app \"Finder\" to open POSIX file \"%s/%s\"'", getcwd(path, MAXPATHLEN), file);
    system(cmd);
```

`path` and `file` are both char[] variables.

I got the clue from [this excerpt](http://www.myths.com/pub/doc/oh_really/other/AppleScript_The_Definitive_Guide/0596005571_applescpttdg-chp-23-sect-2.html) from *Applescript: The Definitive Guide*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example C function for reading a Get Info comment from the finder using AppleScript.

You could modify it for what you want.

```
NSString * readFinderCommentsForFile(NSString * theFile){
/* Need to use AppleScript to read or write Finder Get Info Comments */

/* Convert POSIX file path to hfs path */
NSURL * urlWithPOSIXPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:theFile];
NSString * hfsStylePathString = 
(__bridge_transfer NSString    *)CFURLCopyFileSystemPath((__bridge CFURLRef)  urlWithPOSIXPath, kCFURLHFSPathStyle);

/* Build an AppleScript string */
NSString *appleScriptString = @"tell application \"Finder\"\r get comment of file ";
appleScriptString = [appleScriptString stringByAppendingString:@"\""];
appleScriptString = [appleScriptString stringByAppendingString:hfsStylePathString];
appleScriptString = [appleScriptString stringByAppendingString:@"\""];
appleScriptString = [appleScriptString stringByAppendingString:@"\r end tell\r"];


NSString *finderComment;

NSAppleScript *theScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:appleScriptString];

NSDictionary *theError = nil;
finderComment = [[theScript executeAndReturnError: &theError] stringValue];
NSLog(@"Finder comment is %@.\n", finderComment);


return finderComment;
```

Comment: It is Objective-C code example using an NSAppleScript object and can't be used in C++

Comment: For this project I'm hoping to avoid Cocoa and Objective-C if possible.

Comment: Presumably objective-c as c doesn't use `[`, `]`, `@`, or `:` in the ways exhibited here.

Comment: It's a C function using Objective-C methods.

Comment: Try running that though vanilla c compiler. That simply *isn't* c syntax.